# Manga: young magical fox befriends human knights, fox's parents featured

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story starts with a fox that kind of tells her life so far. She explains that she has a mother who is a strong fox and can use magic. Which then reveals that they are elemental spirits.

That day her mother goes out to do some errands. And the kid gets out of the house because she is terrified and is looking for the city in case her mom is there. She does not find her mom but ends up at a knights building(?).

She is found by a knight there and is very scared of him at first but eventually warms up to him. Eventually the mc becomes friends with all the knights and she is seen as some kind of mascot for the knights.

A few knights go on an expedition because of the sudden heavy snowfall that has been happening. The knights find out eventually that the cause of this is the mother of the mc because she is worried for her child and wants to kill those who “captured” her.

The mc goes back to living with the mom and visits the knights from time to time. She also makes friends with a fire spirit that she met along with the human kingdom’s royals.

The mc eventually also meets her father who is a water spirit that is a snake. When she visits her father he takes care of her a lot and the mother eventually also visits him.

The mc is eventually able to turn into a human because she developed her powers enough.

Comment: You have a good start for an identification question here, but if you can recall any more details it may help. When did you read this manga? In what language? Was it on dead-tree paper or online? Any guess for the magazines or websites that you read? How long is it, eg. just one story or a series spanning multiple issues? Do you recall anything about the art style? Any features from the appearance of the characters? See https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/4918 if you need more ideas for what to mention.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 9):

This is *[Kita no Toride Nite](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kita-no-toride-nite)*.

> Paw pads wrapped in white fur. Fluffiness around the neck. A bushy tail. A rounded figure that was the very definition of fur ball! ――A certain Japanese girl had been **reincarnated into such a fox cub**; Milfiria. Milfiria was told to watch the house by her mother, as the mother left for the capital. However, unable to bear with the loneliness and deciding to chase her mother to the capital, Milfiria became lost in **a fort protected by strong knights**.

The synopsis covers the early details; the main character reincarnates as a fox spirit, with the first few pages being the young fox explaining her life.  Her mother is also a fox but can transform into a woman. Her mother has to go off to the capital to meet the king and leaves her daughter behind; she then gets lonely, tries to go to the capital herself, but gets lost and ends up at a fort.

She's incredibly shy at the fort, largely due to how small she is, but some of the knights manage to win her over. She does become a sort of mascot for them.

The scene with her mother searching for her child is around chapters 10-12; a blizzard starts up and doesn't stop, leading to the knights needing to visit the local snow spirit (the MC's mother).

[image: Mother confronting knights]